# Upload a video to s3 via laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm working on a laravel project that involves uploading videos to s3, but when I try to upload files it always runs "uploading x%" in the bottom left and then goes to a 404 page after it hits 100% (and no file is uploaded to the s3).

Current code:

```
$fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = $request->file('file');
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, fopen($file, 'r+'));
    $fileName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fileName);


    return back()
        ->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.')
        ->with('path',$fileName);}
```

I've also tried the regular, not streamed, upload with the same results. Is this not the correct way to upload videos?

Answer (score 1):

PHP maybe running out of memory if you are trying to upload a big video file.

**Try uploading in streams:**

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($targetFile, fopen($sourceFile, 'r+'));
```

**You can also use streams to download a file from S3 to the local file system:**

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$stream = $disk->getDriver()
               ->readStream($sourceFileOnS3);
file_put_contents($targetFile, stream_get_contents($stream), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: This code gives me ""Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&'"" error. And I was already trying an upload via streaming, could you look at the above code and tell me where I might be going wrong?